# Unexpected results when making multiple assignments in one line separated by comma

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a code which finds the eigenvectors of a matrix given its eigenvalues. I need to write the code myself so inbuilt functions are not an option here.

I already made a simple code to calculate the eigenvalues of a given matrix from which I use these values to calculate the eigenvectors. The problem is that when I solve the homogenous system (*A*−λ*I*)*v*=0 where λ is an eigenvalue of *A* and *I* is the identity matrix, the code returns an empty set, whereas the analytical solution is *x*=*t* where *t* is some free parameter and *y*=0. The code I have is this:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sym
from sympy.solvers.solveset import linsolve

A_1 = sym.Matrix([[0,1],[0,1]])
system = A, b = A_1[:,0], A_1[:,-1]
linsolve(system, x, y)
```

This returns an empty set as I said before. When I print `b` however I get the vector (1,1) which I'm not sure why python is returning this. I need to emphasize that I'm only looking for non-trivial solutions here as I don't want an eigenvector of zeros.

Comment: But you are using nothing but inbuilt functions!?

Comment: `[1,1]` ***is*** an eigenvector w/eigenvalue 1, to see this do the matrix multiplication of `np.array([[0,1],[0,1]])@np.array([1,1])` you'll see that the result is`np.array([1,1])`. This is the definition of an eigenvalue.

Comment: Is your question why `linsolve` returns an empty set? Or why `b` is (1, 1)?

Comment: The `A_1[:,-1]` is selecting the last column of `A_1` which is `[1,1]`. This is assigned to `b` in the second to last line of code.

Comment: @mkrieger1 What I meant is that I don't want a function which directly gives the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a given matrix. Maybe I phrased it incorrectly. I know now why b is (1,1) but why is linsolve returning an empty set.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this statement does what you think it does:

```
system = A, b = A_1[:,0], A_1[:,-1]
```

That will be parsed like this:

```
A, b = A_1[:,0], A_1[:,-1]
System = A, b
```

That first statement is a tuple assignment.  `A` will be assigned `A_1[:,0]`, which is [0,0], and `b` will be assigned the value of `A_1[:,-1]`, which is [1,1].  `system` is then assigned a tuple with both values.

Comment: Then what would be the proper way to write this system? I know why b is returned as a vector (1,1) but I'm not sure why the final output is coming out as an empty set. Could you explain what linsolve(system, x, y) really does?

Comment: So, you are passing [0,0] for the A, and [1,1] for b.  That means you're asking it to find `x` and `y` such that `0x=1` and `0x=1`, and clearly there aren't very many solutions to that.

Comment: Oooh I see now. I managed to solve the problem. Thank you so much!